# Como corrigir este erro "Cannot convert from 'int' to 'char[]'?

Tags: c#, .net, método, argumento

Por que está apresentado esse erro? Acredito que a lógica esteja certa.

[image: Tela do Erro]

Comment: Coloque o código mesmo em texto e a descrição do erro, fica mais fácil para ajudar.

Comment: Quer imprimir os três valores no console? Use esse overload do método `Console.WriteLine(String)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Formatando a saída**

O primeiro argumento do método `WriteLine` deve ser uma string.

Essa string pode conter marcadores para inserir nela, os argumentos seguintes:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", centena, dezena, unidade);
```

**Sobre o erro**

O erro indicado ocorre pois o método `WriteLine` possui mais de uma forma de ser chamado. Uma dessas formas recebe `char[]` no primeiro argumento, seguido de dois `int`s. O que acontece que o compilador está avaliando as alternativas possíveis, e ele achou que era essa que você queria chamar.

Comment: Blza, corrigiu o problema, quer dizer erro era porque não estava convertendo os valores para string? Porque geralmente, acredito eu, bastava colocar os valores dentro Console.WriteLine e ele se virava pra fazer o cast

Comment: Tentei explicar melhor o erro na resposta.

Comment: Olá @Miguel Angelo, valeu mesmo por tentar me explicar, mas acredito que entendi o problema. Eu queria sobrecarregar o método WriteLine somente com numeros interios, porém não existe essa possibilidade, no método geralmente começa com string e depois vem os objetos de acordo com a documentação.

Comment: Exatamente, nenhuma das alternativas desse método recebe 3 inteiros. Acho que o compilador tenta ver qual é a possibilidade que mais bate em termos, no seu caso, tentando passar 3 inteiros, ele achou a alternativa com `char[], int, int`, que possui somente um tipo diferente em relação a `int, int, int`, e ele inferiu que talvez fosse essa que vc quisesse chamar.

Comment: Perfeitamente!!!

Answer (score 4):

Veja a [documentação deste método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads).

Existem diversas sobrecargas para chamá-lo, cada um lida com a informação de uma forma diferente. A maioria é para tipos básicos da linguagem e como pode ser visto só aceita um argumento.

A [sobrecarga que aceita vários argumentos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) não pode ser usado diretamente, o primeiro argumento deve ser uma *string* com a formatação que será aplicada ao conteúdo e depois os argumentos que devem ser impressos usando esta formatação. É esta que deve usar.

Existe uma [outra que aceita mais de um argumento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_). Como esta sobrecarga aceita `int` como segundo e terceiro argumento, é o que mais se aproximou do que parece que precisa, então o compilador escolher equivocadamente esta.

Isto se chama *betterness*.

Neste casos o ideal é usar interpolação de *string*, evita bastante problema e fica mais legível (tem quem discorde). Assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Digite um número com três dígitos");
        if (int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero) && numero < 10000) WriteLine($"{numero / 100} {(numero % 100) / 10} {(numero % 100) % 10}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OSippz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RUxckZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Betterness.cs).

Corrigi outros problemas do código e tornei mais eficiente e simples.

Comment: Verdade Maniero, agora sim entendi o erro. O problema que queria sobrecarregar o método WriteLine somente com valores inteiros.
Mas olhei a documentação e percebi o meu erro. Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Se tivesse sobrecargas para tudo isto geraria uma explosão combinatorial, não é viável. então tem os principais básicos e depois o geral. Se colocar o texto eu monto um código melhor para você.